# R: Error when loading package C50

Tags: r, package

I am receiving the below error when calling the 'C50' package. It has been installed correctly.

*Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘C50’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘inum’*

I have also ran the following .lib path code prior to installing and calling the library:

*.libPaths(c("C:/Users/danhu/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4", .libPaths()))*

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you install `C50` with `install.packages("foo", dependencies = TRUE)` to satisfy dependency requirements? Alternatively, try installing `inum` manually `install.packages("inum")`.

Comment: Perfect, installing inum solved the problem. Thank you, I should have tried that!

Comment: No worries @CafeRacer; glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can install by using a code:
 install.packages("C50", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
 library(C50)

visit:https://rdrr.io/rforge/C50/